# python is.integer() malfunctioning

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer, isinteger

I was doing a test, calculating the minimum n such that for 1/a + 1/b = 1/n, there are at least x distinct solutions. (a, b, n, x are positive integers)

I checked b = 1/(1/n - 1/a) and tested b with `is.integer()`, and the result surprised me.

```
x = 2
n = 1
while(1):
    x0 = 0
    for a in range(n+1,2*n + 1):
        print '-------------'
        print 'a={}'.format(a)
        b = 1.0 / (1.0/n - 1.0/a)
        print 'b={}'.format(b)
        print 'b is integer: ' + str(b.is_integer())
        if b.is_integer():
            print 'a={} b={} n={}'.format(a,b,n)
            x0 += 1
        if x0 * 2 - 1 >= x:
            print n
            exit(0)
    n += 1
```

the output, so why are b = 6.0 and 12.0 not whole numbers?

```
-------------
a=2
b=2.0
b is integer: True
a=2 b=2.0 n=1
-------------
a=3
b=6.0
b is integer: False
-------------
a=4
b=4.0
b is integer: True
a=4 b=4.0 n=2
-------------
a=4
b=12.0
b is integer: False
-------------
a=5
b=7.5
b is integer: False
-------------
a=6
b=6.0
b is integer: True
a=6 b=6.0 n=3
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try something like this

```
    print 'b is integer: ' + str(b.is_integer()), repr(b)
```

You'll see that due to approximations in floating point math, those values are very close to, but not quite integers

Comment: Thanks! Was not aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

In Python2, str is not a faithful representation of a number, it is intended for "user-friendly output". So numbers very close to 6 are output as 6.0. If you want to see the correct output, use repr, or !r specifier in .format.

```
'b = {!r}'.format(b)
```

Or just use Python 3. :-)

Comment: Thanks, that is inspiring.

Comment: Yeah, especially the "just use Py3" bit. :-D